# F#|Fable - Thoth Decode Auto with generics

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I have a function that looks vaguely like this

```
let decodeData<'a> (encodedData: string) = Decode.Auto.fromString<'a>(encodedData)
```

If I do `decodeData<String[]>`, then while the code compiles, at runtime I get a Javascript error of  `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'generics')`

If I remove the generic, and just have `Decode.Auto.fromString<String[]>(encodedData)` it works as expected.

Comment: I seem to remember there was an issue with generic functions in Fable. If you mark functions with generic type parameters as `inline` it should work.

Comment: That works, that is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the JS runtime doesn't have access to type reflection information from F#. The Fable compiler gets around this in some places by using `inline` and resolving the type reflection at compile time.
Some more discussion on adding reflection information [here](https://github.com/fable-compiler/Fable/issues/455).